# Powershell - Selective moving files into subfolder (keeping the newest of each FIRST13 letter grouping)

Tags: powershell

extreme powershell newbie here so please be gentle...

I have a filing system where where files in folders are generated semi-automatically, with multiple versions being kept as redundancy (we really do revert regularly).

Files within the folder are named with the first 13 characters as the identifier, with various dates or initials afterwards.

**12345-A-01-01**_XYZ_20191026.pdf

i.e. the file is 12345-A-01-01 and everything past the first 13 characters is "unpredictable"

- FILE000000001xxxxxxx.pdf
- FILE000000001yyyy.pdf
- FILE000000001zzzzzz.pdf
- FILE000000002xxxx.pdf
- FILE000000002yyy.pdf
- FILE000000002zz.pdf
- FILE000000003xx.pdf
- FILE000000003yyy.pdf
- FILE000000003zzzz.pdf

I'm trying to write a script that can determine the newest version (by date modified file property) of each file "group"
i.e. the newest FILE000000001*.pdf etc

and slide all the others into the .\Superseded subfolder

All I've managed to get so far is a "list" sorting to show the newest at the top of "each" group... now I need to know how to keep that file, and move the others...  any direction or help would be great thanks :)....

```
$_SourcePath = "C:\testfiles"
$_DestinationPath = "C:\testfiles\Superseded"

Get-ChildItem $_SourcePath |
  Where-Object {-not $_.PSIsContainer} |
  Group-Object { $_.Basename.Substring(0,12) } |
foreach {
  $_.Group |
  sort LastWriteTime -Descending 
  } | Move-Item -Destination $_DestinationPath
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are pretty close.  Since you sorted descending order you should just skip the first file:

```
$SourcePath = "C:\testfiles"
$DestinationPath = "C:\testfiles\Superseded"

Get-ChildItem $SourcePath -File |
Group-Object { $_.Basename.Substring(0,12) } |
ForEach-Object {
    $_.Group |
    Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
    Select-Object -skip 1 | 
    Move-Item -Destination $DestinationPath -WhatIf
    # Note: Above, the move has to be in each iteration of the loop
    #       so we skip the first (newest) of each file.
    }
```

You don't need `Where-Object {-not $_.PSIsContainer}` , use the `-File` Parameter instead.

Also I wouldn't name your variables `$_***`.  That's bound to get confused with `$_` like the pipeline variable.

I added `-WhatIf` to the move command so you can test without causing any damage ...

I didn't test it, but it looks about right.

Comment: Thanks Steven, 

Ah ok so that's the format.... good to learn

But I suspect that will only leave me 1 file for the entire folder - where I need it to identify and skip the newest of each "group" of files...

Comment: You're right. Sorry I didn't spot that.  I updated the answer.  The skip & move stuff needs to be in the loop.  This way the first of each grouping is being skipped.  Let me know if that's closer.

Comment: That's perfect thank you @Steven - that works like charm :)  

I thought this might be suitable for powershell, but that's impressively succint...  


I don't yet know the language/syntax - Thank you for helping me in my first steps to leave vbscript behind!